# How can I move a CGPath without creating a new one

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgpath

I am creating a `CGPath` to define an area in my game like this:

```
CGPathMoveToPoint   ( myPath, NULL, center.x, center.y );
CGPathAddLineToPoint( myPath, NULL,center.x + 100, center.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint( myPath, NULL, center.x + 100, center.y + 100);
CGPathAddLineToPoint( myPath, NULL, center.x,  center.y + 100);
CGPathCloseSubpath  ( myPath );
```

I know this is just a square and that I could just use another `CGRect` but the path I wish to actually create is not actually a rectangle (I am just testing at the moment). And then detecting the touch area simply with a:

```
if (CGPathContainsPoint(myPath, nil, location, YES))
```

This all works fine, the problem is that the `CGPath` may be moving up to 40 times per second. How can I move it without having to create a new one? I know I can do something like this to "move" it:

```
center.y += x;
CGPathRelease(myPath);
myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint   ( myPath, NULL, center.x, center.y );
CGPathAddLineToPoint( myPath, NULL,center.x + 100, center.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint( myPath, NULL, center.x + 100, center.y + 100);
CGPathAddLineToPoint( myPath, NULL, center.x,  center.y + 100);
CGPathCloseSubpath  ( myPath );
```

But I have to release and create a new path up to 40 times per second, which I think might have a performance penalty; is this true?

I would like to be able to move it just like I am currently moving some `CGRects` by simply setting the origin to a different value, is this possible with `CGPath`?

Thank you.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I don't have a GraphicsContext as I am not drawing on a `UIView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying a transformation to the CGPath and test against a point, is equivalent to applying the *inverse* transformation to the point.

Therefore, you can use

```
CGPoint adjusted_point = CGPointMake(location.x - center.x, location.y - center.y);
if (CGPathContainsPoint(myPath, NULL, adjusted_point, YES))
```

But `CGPathContainsPoint` already takes a `CGAffineTransform` parameter (which you have `NULL`-ed it), so you can also use

```
CGAffineTransform transf = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-center.x, -center.y);
if (CGPathContainsPoint(myPath, &transf, location, YES))
```

---

If you are drawing, instead of changing the path, you can change the CTM in your drawing code directly.

```
CGContextSaveGState(c);
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, center.x, center.y);
// draw your path
CGContextRestoreGState(c);
```

Use a `CAShapeLayer` if you need performance.

Comment: Wouldn't that move the whole graphic context and not just the path?. Also I forgot to mention I do not have a graphicscontext as I am not drawing on a UIView

Comment: Thank you that will help me a lot!. Instead of having to move all my polys I can just translate my points, I should have thought about that before. Just one more question in performance what is better to create a new cgpoint or to use the CGAffine transform?

Comment: I think create a new CGPoint is faster as applying the transform involves extra multiplications.

Comment: The CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation is not being applied to the point for some reason...

Answer (score 4):

@KennyTM's answer worked perfectly for the purpose of the OP, but the question remains:

> **How can I move a CGPath without creating a new one?**

Well, two lines of code did the trick for me:

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:cgPath];
[path applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(2.f, 0.f)];
```

Comment: There is also: CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(
CGPathRef path,const CGAffineTransform *transform);

Comment: @Antoine thanks, but that still creates a new CGPath, which what the OP was trying to avoid. If the issue was better, cleaner code, your answers is perfect.

Comment: Yes I know. Unfortunately, what the OP was looking for is OS X NSBezierPath method  `setAssociatedPoints:atIndex:` You can use this method to change the points associated with a path quickly and without recreating the path. I hope in the future UIBezierPath will behave more like a NSBezierPath.